# PowerBI Matrix adding separate dimensions related to row only

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

There are 3 tables, sales and inventory tables relate to product table by product_name.

product table: product_name, category, price

sales table: product_name, month_name, sold_qty

inventory table: product_name, location_name, stock_qty

Expected results:
[image: WantedResults]

I would like to create a matrix visual as illustrated.

Attempt 1:
In "Matrix" visual, I tried to add [month_name] and [location_name] to Columns, [qty] and [stock_qty] to Values.
Problems:

1. [month_name] and [location_name] do not coexist, 'Show next level' will reveal another one but not both
2. the same aggregated [sold_qty] value repeated for each location_name or aggregated [stock_qty] repeated for each [month_name] (just like unreleated dimenions in Pivot table)
3. unable to separate placement of Columns and Values in their own group

Attempt 2:
I also tried it in "Table" visual by creating individual Measures one by one. It works but its very ineffective and lots of hard code Measures.

Attempt 3:
Using a measure_group table: grp, measure_name
to group the individual measures in Attempt 2 and use a super mega measure that put every single value I needed into it in the form of:
If ( max ( measure_group[measure_name] ) = "Messure 1", [Measure 1]),
If ( max ( measure_group[measure_name] ) = "Messure 2", [Measure 2]), '''))

Attempt 4:
Do it on ETL side, prepare the required data and fit it into a single table.

Do you have suggestion on how to achieve it in Matrix? Thank you.